# ERROR with Map_Server. Not able to open .yaml file. Using prebuilt Map with AMCL launch file- how to execute with RVIZ

Tags: navigation, rviz, roslaunch, map-server, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I currently have made my map using Hector Slam and saved the map as .yaml file and .pgm .

I have downloaded the Navigation stack as well using git source: https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation.git . Also ran catkin_make afterwards.

Now, I am trying to implement AMCL by placing my robot( irobot create 2) onto the map and do autonomous mapping.

I am getting an error when i run am amcl file... which says " MapServer could not open <.yaml> file."
Please see attached for my code.

[Screenshot from 2017-03-23 10-48-08.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14902805617711089.png)

Update:

I was able to upload map onto RVIZ, and executed amcl with proper tf/ messages.
However, when I move the robot towards a location, the PoseArray points do not move.
Please recommend a suggestion.
Here is the screen pic. [Screenshot from 2017-03-23 14-55-11.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14902953293753205.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257557/error-with-map_server.-not-able-to-open-.yaml-file.-using-prebuilt-map-with-amcl-launch-file--how-to-execute-with-rviz./) by [Shilpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29620/shilpan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2017-03-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shilpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29620/shilpan/) on 2017-03-22**:
I ran the following commands simultaneously..
roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch
rosrun map_server map_server .yaml
roslaunch amcl amcl_diff.launch

but received message "No laser scan rece

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosrun map_server map_server <file_name>.yaml
rosrun rviz rviz --> Add Map->topic /map

Issue resolved.
Added tf code messages in AMCL launch file to configure  with my robot.

Please see for follow up Q.  [link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/257816/robot-not-moving-on-prebuilt-map-in-rviz-amcl/)

---

Originally posted by [Shilpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29620/shilpan/) with karma: 96 on 2017-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0